# how to choose prime for implementing Diffie-hellman key exchange

Tags: python, security

I am currently writing code to implement Diffie-Hellman key exchange based on RFC 2631 and RFC 3526.

As you can see in the RFC 3526, there are many groups such as 
1536-bit MODP Group // 
2048-bit MODP Group //
3072-bit MODP Group //
4096-bit MODP Group //
6144-bit MODP Group //
8192-bit MODP Group

What should I be based when choosing one group from those groups??

Can you tell me how to choose one group from those groups for Diffie-Hellman key exchange and reasons as well?

Comment: You can look into this for your query :https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/where-do-i-get-prime-numbers-for-diffie-hellman-can-i-use-them-twice.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should be aware of is that using a fixed prime that comes from a standard [carries some risk](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/2015/10/14/how-is-nsa-breaking-so-much-crypto/).  Having said that, I am fairly confident that the NSA cannot crack any of these, but that does not mean they won't be able to reach the smallest one XXX years from now.

The key size you choose all comes down to the security you require.  The best algorithms we know for breaking Diffie Hellman are not too different than the best algorithms we have for factoring.  In a nutshell, 1024-bit and below is a no-no, yet 2048-bit and above isn't going to fall any time soon (unless there is a mathematical breakthrough or quantum computers become practical, and if the latter happens, then DH is doomed altogether).

So what do we know about what is crackable?

- In 2010, a [768-bit number was factored](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/006.pdf).  Authors concluded "Another conclusion from our work is that we can confidently say that if we restrict ourselves
  to an open community, academic effort as ours and unless something dramatic happens in factoring, we will not be able to factor a 1024-bit RSA modulus within the next five years (cf. [30]). After that, all bets are off."
- This year, a [768-bit prime discrete logarithm was computed](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/067.pdf) (proving that 768-bit DH is breakable).  The authors wrote: "Also, we explicitly illustrate in Section 3
  that continued usage of 1024-bit prime field ElGamal or DSA keys is much riskier than it is for 1024-bit RSA (all are still commonly used), because once a successful attack has been conducted against a single well-chosen prime field all users of that prime field may be affected at little additional effort."

As you can see, there is no indication that 1536-bit is close to being attacked, which might suggest that any key size is fine.  However, given what we know about the dangers of using a hard-coded prime, you might want to err on the safe side and use at least 2048-bit.

In all honesty, I wouldn't panic about going beyond that.  Yes, there are many people who think one should use at least 4096-bit or higher.  However, I have not seen any of those people understand the mathematics of breaking these algorithms.  The biggest irony is that when those people recommend using 4096-bit RSA or DH to exchange a 256-bit AES key, not realising that they have downgraded the security of the AES key.  As noted in [Unbelievable Security Matching AES security using public key systems](http://iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480067.pdf), "Matching AES-192 or AES-256 security levels with public key systems requires public key sizes far beyond anything in regular use today."  i.e. 192-bit AES key corresponds to 7000-bit RSA/DH and 256-bit AES corresponds to 16000-bit RSA/DH.

Bottom line: Go with 2048-bit MODP Group and don't panic.  You're much more likely to have [implementation problems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.305.930&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that break your crypto than you are to have somebody cracking the number based upon its size.